# Visual Studio 2012 System.Exception error

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I just started developing for **Windows 8 store**. Even though I open a sample project and start debugging it displays this error.

An unhandled exception of type `System.Exception` occurred in Unknown Module.
Activation of the Windows Store app `'a9c71d52-8ba1-460a-aa8f-df5ea89f1efa_qpttb2q7b6s4m!App'` failed with error **The app didn't start**.
The program `'[2520] App8.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352)`.

I have tried to remove references and adding them but they aren't happening. Kindly help me with this weird problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching and not able to get an answer. I reinstalled Windows 8 and with a new version of VisualStudio everything is in rhythm now.